# Создать повторяющийся цикл

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть код, который работает, можно сказать, что в перечислении от заданного числа к меньшему
Допустим, вписав число 9, будет перечисляться 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 и введётся Stop
Как сделать так, чтобы программа сама написала число 9, но не достигала числа 0 и последним число было 1, а от 1 шла обратно до 9 и так всё заново, чтобы был постоянно повторяющийся цикл

```
x = int(input())

while x > 0:
    y = x
    while y > 0:
        y -= 1
        print(y)
        x -= 1

print("stop")
```

Можно задать дополнить так:

```
name = 9

print(name)

if name == "9"
```

То перечисление идёт от 9 до 1 и обратно, а том от 1 до 9

Comment: Можно тупо сделать два цикла друг за другом один по `range(1, int(x)+1)`, другой по `range(int(x), 0, -1)` и всё это в бесконечном цикле `while True`. Есть и другие варианты. Подумайте. Можно сделать шаг `delta = 1` и в конце цикла инвертировать его `delta = -delta`.

Comment: А как должен выглядеть код полностью готовым?

Comment: Если это учебное задание, то вы должны сделать его сами. Иначе какой смысл? Я вам уже и подсказки дал.

Comment: Хммм) Хорошо, а мне нужно будет что то убирать из моего кода?

Comment: Циклы в любом случае должны быть другие

Comment: @CrazyElf C `range()` можно и одним `for`'ом обойтись.

Answer (score 3):

Я, как обычно, с извращенной формулой:

```
for k in range(50):
    print(abs(k % 16 - 8) + 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
start = 1
end   = 9
while True:   # если надо бесконечно бегать туда-сюда
    for i in (*range(start, end+1), *range(end-1, start, -1)):
        print(i)
```

Comment: Хм, забавно. Но, думаю, если это учебное задание, то как-то слишком будет ))

Comment: Не совсем домашнее, я учусь, но для ознакомления хотел попробовать
Сейчас понимаю о чём всё таки шла речь
Но всё равно всем спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Сначала обращу внимание на то, что у вас бессмысленный цикл внутри цикла. Выход из них происходит одновременно, так как Х и У при каждой итерации становятся равны друг другу.

Ну а бесконечный цикл с вашей задачей можно реализовать так:

```
x = int(input())
y = x
while x: # пока Х существует работает главный цикл
    while y > 0: # прогоняем цикл от Х до 0
        print(y) # сначала выводим на печать, что бы "1" было последним напечатанным
        y -= 1
    while y < x:
        y += 1
        print(y)
# далее код не выполнится, так как главный цикл будет выполняться бесконечно
print("stop")
```

Будут выводиться последовательности типа:

54321123455432112345...

987654321123456789987654321123456789...

321123321123321123...